# How to substitute value of variables in Python expression, but not evaluate the expression?

Tags: python, eval

I have a Python expression that looks like the following:

```
var1 = 'GOOGLE'
var2 = '5'
expr = 'df[df[var1]>=var2]'
```

In my workspace var1 and var2 are well defined so I can evaluate expr as follows:

```
eval(expr)
```

However, I want to pass this expr (as string) to another function with values of var1 and var2 substituted in it. I do not want to pass the variables var1 and var2, as I can have any number of variables, not just two. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: I'd use a dictionary or a custom object to collect all the variables you want to pass to your function in one input argument. Would this work for your problem?

Comment: What is your question? As of now your question is not clear. Do you want to know how to create a function that takes varying (any amount) arguments or what?

Comment: @PieCot Yes, that's a possible solution, but I want the variables to be substituted so that the person handling the task downstream need not worry about variable substitutions.

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea: I just want to convert the string df[df[var1]>=var2] to df[df['GOOG']>=5] without evaluating it.

Comment: @Zing Simply use f-string

Comment: Another very dumb solution is using `replace`, but it is very dangerous in my opinion: `expr.replace('var1', f"'{var1}'").replace('var2', var2)`. I wouldn't use it. Clearly, you can automatize, iterating on all the variables you want to replace.

Comment: @flakes: Thanks for spending your time to let me know that it is and XY problem.

Comment: @Zing Did I answer your question?

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea: That looks like the solution, but will require me to add curly braces in the expr before I use it. Thanks.

Comment: @Zing don't forget to mark it as correct✅ if I answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the expression with `ast.parse` and use a subclass of `ast.NodeTransformer` to convert `Name` nodes to the corresponding values as `Constant` nodes, and then convert the AST back to code with `ast.unparse`:

```
import ast

var1 = 'GOOGLE'
var2 = '5'
expr = 'df[df[var1]>=var2]'

class NamesToConstants(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        if node.id in globals(): # feel free to use your own dict instead of globals()
            value = globals()[node.id]
            try: # convert value to integer if viable
                value = int(value)
            except:
                pass
            return ast.Constant(value=value)
        return node

tree = ast.parse(expr)
NamesToConstants().visit(tree)
print(ast.unparse(tree))
```

This outputs:

```
df[df['GOOGLE'] >= 5]
```

`ast.unparse` requires Python 3.10 or later. If you're using an earlier version, you can use `astunparse.unparse` from the [astunparse package](https://github.com/simonpercivall/astunparse) instead.

Demo: https://trinket.io/python3/18cc1182d0

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Python f-string as demonstrated below

```py
expr = f'df[df[{var1}] >= {var2}]'
```

Comment: This is a possible solution, but will require me to add curly braces around variables that I wanted to avoid.

Comment: The whole point was *not* to alter the original expression, but to produce a literal expression without evaluating it at the end. If you are parsing arbitrary expressions or statements (e.g. from a file), you don't know in advance which variables exist and where.

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" way would be to do use `ast.parse`, as @blhsing recommended. Still, in many cases this may be an overkill. In your simple case and similar cases, this is what I would do:

```py
import re

expression = "3*x + function_x(y)"
values = {'x': 2, 'y': 5}  # feel free to use a subset of `globals()` or `locals()` here, to reflect your workspace

# Substitute variable symbols with their values
for var, val in values.items():
    pattern = r'\b' + re.escape(var) + r'\b'
    expression = re.sub(pattern, str(val), expression)
    
assert(expression == "3*2 + function_x(5)")
```

The `r'\b'` pattern ensures that you only match whole-word occurences, in case a variable exists as a substring of another variable or function/built-in name etc (like `x` here exists in `function_x`).

The `re.escape()` function is necessary when you have variable symbols that contain special characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions. For example, the variable symbol itself could contain a special character, such as a `.`: `y.z`.